# Открытие картинки по пути мойсайт.ру/папка

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки.

У меня такой вопрос. Вот если в PHP создал папку "папка" и кинул туда файл index.php, то можно этот скрипт открыть так: мойсайт.ру/папка - а как такое сделать с картинкой? Допустим, название картники 123.png. Т.е. чтобы картинка открывалась например: мойсайт.ру/папка.

Answer (score 2):

Либо в настройках сайта изменить дефолтный файл с index.html, например, на index.jpg (или на нужный 123.png) - это можно. Как менять - в справку своего сервера.

Либо в энтот самый файл поместить команды теневого редиректа на картинку (без изменения адреса в браузере). Как - в справку языка программирования, тема: HTTP-заголовки.
Для PHP:

```
header("Location: нюнюню/123.png",TRUE,302);
exit;
```

Можно просто в файл поместить html, в теле которого только эта картинка.

Зависит метод от цели такого деяния.